# Best approach to write generic azure logic app/azure functions to do FTP operations

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to build a FTP service using azure logic apps/azure functions. I would like the logic app to be invoked via HTTP request (will expose this app as REST API later). The FTP server details like directory, username, password will be sent in the request.

Is there a way by which I can have my logic app to create FTP connector dynamically based on the incoming request and then do a FTP upload or download?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a connection at Logic Apps run time, it need to happen at author time. If it's a pre-defined list of connections, you can create them first, then use switch-case to branch into the connection that should be used at run time.